# Error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when calling SOAP cilent in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Here is the data from wsdl

```
<s:element name="CreateDraftLead">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="formId" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FirstName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LastName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Gender" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AgeGroup" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MobilePhone" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Birthday" nillable="true" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="District" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="email" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Region" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LocationId" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LeadSourceId" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CompanyId" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SourceCampaignId" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AllowEmail" nillable="true" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Questions" type="tns:ArrayOfQuestion"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfQuestion">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Question" nillable="true" type="tns:Question"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="Question">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

And here is my attempt code

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://demo/demo.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1, "exception" => 0));


        $data = array(
            'formId' => 1,
            'LocationId' => 1,
            'FirstName' => 'test',
            'LastName' => 'test',
            'MobilePhone' => 11111111,
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'AllowEmail' => 0,
            'Region' => 'HK',
            'LeadSourceId' => 11,
            'Questions' => array(
                "Question" => array("AgeGroup" => 10),
                "Question" => array("Gender" => 1),
                "Question" => array("Remarks" => 'test'),
                "Question" => array("Are you currently a member of any yoga or fitness centre?  " => 'Yes'),
            )
        );



        $result = $client->CreateDraftLead(array('parameters' => $data));

        var_dump($result);
```

Is this caused by the structure of the input data, how to fix that? Thanks for helping.

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_soap.php:60 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_soap.php(60): SoapClient->__call('CreateDraftLead', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_soap.php(60): SoapClient->CreateDraftLead(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_soap.php on line 60
```

**Updated:**

Thanks for helping. right now can send to server

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://demo/demo.asmx?wsdl");

$data = array(
    'formId' => '1',
    'FirstName' => 'test',
    'LastName' => 'test',
    //'Gender' => 1,
    //'AgeGroup' => 10,
    'MobilePhone' => '11111111',
    'Birthday' => null,
    'District' => 'HK',
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'Region' => 'HK',
    'LocationId' => 1,
    'LeadSourceId' => 11,
    'CompanyId' => null,
    'SourceCampaignId' => null,
    'AllowEmail' => false,
    'Questions' => array(
        "Question" => array("AgeGroup" => 10),
        "Question" => array("Gender" => 1),
        "Question" => array("Remarks" => 'test'),
        "Question" => array("Are you currently a member of any yoga or fitness centre?  " => 'Yes'),
    )
);

$result = $client->__soapCall("CreateDraftLead", array($data));

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Problems remain are :

1) AllowEmail takes boolean but either 0,1,true,false return error :
Invalid column name 'false' / Invalid column name 'true' from the server , but it is not exception

2) is minOccurs='1' means must provide? as tested can ignore the field and server still return success

Thanks for great effort.

Comment: is this the full wsdl source?

Comment: If your original question was answered, you should mark the answer accepted, not edit your question to add more questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try out the following (not tested):

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://demo/demo.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1, "exception" => 0));

$data = array(
    'formId' => 1,
    'LocationId' => 1,
    'FirstName' => 'test',
    'LastName' => 'test',
    'MobilePhone' => 11111111,
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'AllowEmail' => 0,
    'Region' => 'HK',
    'LeadSourceId' => 11,
    'Questions' => array(
        "Question" => array("AgeGroup" => 10),
        "Question" => array("Gender" => 1),
        "Question" => array("Remarks" => 'test'),
        "Question" => array("Are you currently a member of any yoga or fitness centre?  " => 'Yes'),
    )
);

$result = $client->__soapCall("CreateDraftLead", array($data));

var_dump($result);
```

Also it seems that you do not provide all neccessary infomration like `Gender` and so on.. you should check this aswell.

Comment: thanks now the input is ok , the only problem is server return ["CreateDraftLeadResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["status"]=> bool(false) ["Message"]=> string(28) "Invalid column name 'false'." ["FormId"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: it is caused by the 'AllowEmail' , which accept the boolean type, how to post the boolean type to SOAP, tested 0 , false are not ok

Comment: In general `0`,`1`, `false` and `true`are valid values (case sensitive)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. Tested all 0,1, false, true, return the error "Invalid column name false" . But if I ignore it / post null, the server return success, is this possibly the service problem?

Comment: Can you update the array you send to the server? seems to be a problem in the data structure.

Comment: Try to send `'AllowEmail' => "0",` instead of `'AllowEmail' => 0,` this might fix the prob

Comment: still same error message, and I found that "0" ,0 , false are interchangeable , also mean false

Comment: Might be a problem with the service, as far as this is not neccessary for you, you might just skip this value

Answer (score 3):

You can use "0" or **intval(false)**

```
<?php
  $client = new SoapClient("http://demo/demo.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1, "exception" => 0));

 $data = array(
   'formId' => 1,
   'LocationId' => 1,
   'FirstName' => 'test',
   'LastName' => 'test',
   'MobilePhone' => 11111111,
   'email' => 'test@test.com',
   'AllowEmail' => "0",
   'Region' => 'HK',
   'LeadSourceId' => 11,
   'Questions' => array(
       "Question" => array("AgeGroup" => 10),
       "Question" => array("Gender" => 1),
       "Question" => array("Remarks" => 'test'),
       "Question" => array("Are you currently a member of any yoga or fitness centre?  " => 'Yes'),
   )
 );

$result = $client->__soapCall("CreateDraftLead", array($data));

var_dump($result);
```

OR

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://demo/demo.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1, "exception" => 0));

$data = array(
   'formId' => 1,
   'LocationId' => 1,
   'FirstName' => 'test',
   'LastName' => 'test',
   'MobilePhone' => 11111111,
   'email' => 'test@test.com',
   'AllowEmail' => intval(false),
   'Region' => 'HK',
   'LeadSourceId' => 11,
   'Questions' => array(
       "Question" => array("AgeGroup" => 10),
       "Question" => array("Gender" => 1),
       "Question" => array("Remarks" => 'test'),
       "Question" => array("Are you currently a member of any yoga or fitness centre?  " => 'Yes'),
   )
);

$result = $client->__soapCall("CreateDraftLead", array($data));

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: sorry for late reply. it return Invalid column name 'false'.

Answer (score 3):

I would test one more trick for sending boolean to your service:

```
// most probably a solution
'AllowEmail' => new \SoapVar('true', XSD_STRING, 's:boolean')
// or less probably solution, but still possible I guess
'AllowEmail' => new \SoapVar('true', XSD_BOOLEAN, 's:boolean')
```

I assume this is way to do it, as when you are trying to send `0|1|true|false` it returns a wierd error of *no such COLUMN*.

> 2) is minOccurs='1' means must provide? as tested can ignore the field and server still return success

I guess so. But it still stays on implementation on other side. I was integrating once an API with WSDL extremety far from what you were able to do with it.

Comment: sorry for late reply, both of them still return the error : Invalid column name 'true'.

Comment: So I would send it to support of API you are working with. It is obviously a mistake on their side for me.